# Sequelize Where condition in nested include

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

How can I get make the below sql statement in Sequelize with include?

```
select
    *
from
    User_Role_Table as user_role
inner join User_Table as u on
    u.User_ID = user_role.User_ID
inner join Role_Table as r on
    r.User_Role_ID = user_role.User_Role_ID
where
    u.User_ID = u_id AND r.Role_Name = 'role_name'
```

I have tried putting where condition inside the include, but there is a error if there is no record found.

```
UserRole.findOne({
        where: {
            userId,
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: User,
                as: "users",
                required: true,
            },
            {
                model: Role,
                as: "roles",
                require: true,
                where: {
                    roleName,
                },
            },
        ],
    })
```

Is it possible I can put the where condition inside the include into the outsite initial where block? I have tried the below, but it return error:  `SequelizeDatabaseError: The multi-part identifier "UserRole.roleName" could not be bound.`

```
UserRole.findOne({
        where: {
            userId,
            "$Role.roleName$": roleName,//roleName condition write here
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: User,
                as: "users",
                required: true,
            },
            {
                model: Role,
                as: "roles",
                require: true,
            },
        ],
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the `where` on each of the joins.

```js
const userRole = await UserRole.findOne({
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      where: {
        User_ID: userId,
      },
    },
    {
      model: Role,
      where: {
        Role_Name: roleName,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```